# block in assert_valid_keys: Unknown key: :optional (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Upon pushing my latest commit to heroku, I've been recieving this error, and can't seem to find where it's coming from:

> app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:75:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :optional. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :foreign_type, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache (Argum
>   entError)

Can't seem to figure out why am recieving this error when in development it doesn't occur. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your models? Also Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: @Pavan I'm using rails version 4.2.5.1, unless I must upgrade the version I will provide the models though the `:optional` method/key is not used in any of them.

Comment: It seems that you have `optional` key somewhere in your code. If so it has been added in Rails 5.x

Comment: @Pavan I don't recall using the `optional` key ever as my code has been working in production fine except the last few days. Is this caused due to using an older version of Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I found that i can get this error if i put the optional key on the `has_many` side of the model. It is only defined for the `belongs_to` side.